# Powershell(cmd too) doesn't recognize special characters "ą, ę" etc

Tags: powershell, special-characters

Powershell does not recognize special characters such as: "ą", "ę", "ć" etc.
when using something like that:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content test.txt | findstr /c:something

??? something 

PS C:\> Get-Content test.txt | findstr /c:ę => nil
```

As you mayguess any special character will show question mark.

I use to run ruby scripts and while every character from script is working as intended when i run `$stdin.gets.chomp` the input with special character is showing as empty box.

```
input = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts input => ▯
```

And it shows empty square box (with earlier version of Powershell it used question marks instead)

I was trying https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/ but that does not work for me.

For any helpful advice i will be thankful.

Edit: Changing chcp to 1250 than $OutputEncoding =[Console]::OutputEncoding
shows "ąęą something" when findstr /c:something but doesn't show anything when findstr /c:ę.  Changing chcp creates compability issues when in ruby.

Edit2: Rest of my researches goes there [Ruby compatibility error encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029914/ruby-compatibility-error)

Thanks

Comment: Does that also occur, when you add `-encoding unicode` to your `get-Content` cmdlet?

Comment: i'm newbie here but if i do  Get-Content -encoding utf8 test.txt | findstr /c:ę or Get-Content test.txt -encoding utf8 | findstr /c:ę it still shows nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using pure powershell, not mixing with executables (**-match** instead of **findstr**):

```
Get-Content C:\temp\encoding.txt -Encoding Unicode| ? {$_ -match "ę"}
```

Finds occurences in the file (when txt is saved as Unicode):

```
Get-Content C:\temp\encoding.txt -Encoding Unicode

ę 
asd
ęę
#ääöpl
```

My file contained 4 lines, as shown above

```
Get-Content C:\temp\encoding.txt -Encoding Unicode| ? {$_ -match "ę"}

ę 
ęę
```

Comment: `(Get-Content C:\temp\encoding.txt -Encoding Unicode) -cmatch "ę"`

Comment: @JosefZ What is `cmatch` in powershell? Never heard of and a quick search engine call `powershell cmatch` did not improve my ps knowledge.

Comment: @timo Case sensitive match. By default -match is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

#### German Characters - "Umlaute" like Ä,Ö with UTF8

##### Powershell ISE/Terminal

```
$file='c:/test.txt'
# content of $file: Verknüpfung mit einem Master..

get-content $file -encoding utf8
```

##### Expected / Actual Output

Verknüpfung mit einem Master..