# Ruby compatibility error encoding

Tags: ruby, powershell, encoding, special-characters

I'm having a problem. Let's look:

> C:\temp> ruby script.rb

```
script.rb                 => Powershell output

puts "ę"                  => ę #irb \xA9
puts "\xA9"               => ▯
puts "ę"=="\xA9"          => false
input = $stdin.gets.chomp => input=="ę"
puts "e#{input}e"         => eęe
puts "ę"==input           => false
puts "ę#{input}"          => Encoding::Compatibility Error Utf8 & CP852

irb                       => #command line in ruby
puts "ę"=="\xA9"          => true
input = $stdin.gets.chomp => input=="ę"
puts "ę"==input           => true  && "\xA9"==input => true
puts "ę#{input}"          => ęę
```

It looks like powershell's input uses other font for all special characters than ruby and notepad++(?). Can i change that so it will work when i type in prompt(when asked) and does not show an error?

Edit: Sorry for misdirection. I added invoke and specified that file has extension ".rb" not ".txt"
Edit2: Ok, I've researched some more information and I've been trying do some encoding(UTF8) to a variable. Somethin' strange occured.

```
puts "ę#{input.encoding}"         => ęCP852
puts "\xA9"                       => UTF-8
```

Encoding to CP852 has revealed that encoding pass on bytes. I learned that value of "ę"=20+99=119, "ą" = 20 + 85, 20 = C4

Ok. got it ".encoding" - shows what encoding i use. And that resolve this problem.

```
puts "ę#{input.encode "UTF-8"}"         => ęę
```

Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: Can you explain how you're invoking these differently? Where does powershell fit in exactly?

Comment: I edited. Under Powershell output is powershell output.

Comment: FYI: In UTF-8, hex code of `"ę"` is `0x119`. `"\u{00A9}"` is `"©"`. Your powershell seems to be working in CP852 (hello, windows!)

Comment: Check my answer on your (same) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025963/powershellcmd-too-doesnt-recognize-special-characters-%c4%85-%c4%99-etc
Its all about encoding..

Comment: Is there a way for two to work together?

Comment: @mudasobwa  FYI: In **UTF-8**, hex code of "`ę`" (Unicode codepoint `U+0119` i.e. UTF-16 `\u0119`) is byte sequence `0xC4` `0x99`

Comment: @JosefZ yes, indeed, I meant codepoint writing “hex code.”

Comment: @Martin while executing ruby script in powershell it ask you for input, and the input isn't in UTF8 so it gives an error. Is there a way to omit it?

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, don't forget to have `# encoding: UTF-8` at the top of your Ruby script.

Comment: If you've found a solution, post that as an answer and accept it. That helps other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input in prompt( either cmd or powershell) is causing problems due to incompatibility of using differents encodings just try to encode it via methods in script`.encode "UTF-8" #in case of Ruby language` If you dont know what methods do that just google `your_language_name encoding`